# Validate insert between hours range

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, insert

I have problem. 
I trying to write validation that will reject insert when someone will try to put employee between times.

Someone added employee to system between hours start 07:00 end 15:00. I am trying to make validation that user can't add time between ours before he added on employee.

```
select case 
  when exists 
  (
    select * 
    from elements e 
    where @ELM_DateColumn1#QD@ BETWEEN @ELM_DateColumn1#QD@ and  @ELM_DateColumn2#QD@ 
      and @ELM_DateColumn2#QD@ BETWEEN @ELM_DateColumn1#QD@ and  @ELM_DateColumn2#QD@
      and e.elm_fflid=200 and e.ELM_EmpID=@ELM_EmpID@ 
      and e.elm_datecolumn3= @ELM_DateColumn3#Q@
   )
   then @Error@
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below:

```
IF EXISTS(/*use select statement here*/)
BEGIN
    /*do something if select statement returns a result*/
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    /*do something else if select statement returns no results*/
END
```

Comment: Sory but still don't have a clue how to write it :/